# Precise timing in Python in a multithreaded enviornment

Tags: python, multithreading, time, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am trying to replay a log file of CAN messages onto a virtual bus in Python. The log file contains a list of timestamped messages, and I want to keep the same timing of those messages when I send them on the bus. The absolute time of the timestamp isn't important, but the time difference between two points of a signal is crucial, otherwise the signal will be distorted. I have tried two approaches: time.sleep() and a while loop busy wait. Neither seem to produce satisfactory results, the delay times being slow, inaccurate, and inconsistent. What is the best way to achieve accurate delays within a millisecond or two in a multithreaded Python environment? Here is a code snippet to show the use case:

```
def busy_wait(self, duration_in_ms):
    target_time = time.perf_counter() + (duration_in_ms / 1000.0)
    while time.perf_counter() < target_time:
        pass

# Task to handle replaying CAN messages
async def can_task(self):
    while True:
        if self.msg_recv_queue.qsize() > 0:
            msg = self.msg_recv_queue.get()
            delay = (msg[1] - self.last_msg_sendtime)
            if(delay > 0):
                self.busy_wait(delay)

            self.bus.send(can.Message(arbitration_id = msg[0], data = msg[3], is_extended_id = False))
            self.last_msg_sendtime = msg[1]
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
```

Comment: You will get jitter from your sleep time. Best is having your routine called as in [data_received](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.Protocol.data_received) when something arrives. Your code then does nothing until there is a packet to process. Thread context switching will also cause some jitter as threads still use one CPU.